# Android - Limit Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT to a specific file extension

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

In my app I need to get an Audio file from the user's library.

to do it I'm calling this Intent:

```
Intent selectIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            selectIntent.setType("audio/*");
            startActivityForResult(selectIntent, SONG_REQUEST_CODE);
```

by having "audio/*" as an argument for the setType() method, I'm getting every audio file, indipendently from it's extension.

**All I need to do is to filter it to only have, let's say, .mp3 files selectable**

I tried to do it by having ".mp3", "audio/.mp3" as an argument for the `setType()` method, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step #1: Find the MIME type for the file type you want. In the case of MP3, that is `audio/mpeg`.

Step #2: Pass that MIME type into `setType()`, instead of `audio/*`.

Note that `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` has nothing to do with file extensions, in part because `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` has nothing to do with files.

Answer (score 3):

I am using following code

```
Intent mp3Intent;
mp3Intent= new Intent();
mp3Intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
mp3Intent.setType("audio/mpeg");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(mp3Intent, getString(R.string.audio_file_title)), REQ_CODE_PICK_SOUNDFILE);
```

and getting uri in **onActivityResult** by using following code -:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_PICK_SOUNDFILE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if ((data != null) && (data.getData() != null)){
            Uri mp3FileUri = data.getData();
            // Now you can use that Uri by passing to your MediaPlayer or can use ContentResolver and OutputInputStream() to read MP3 encode byte
            }
        }
}
```

for more extension and MIME types you can visit [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/)

I think this may help you.

Comment: "Now you can use that Uri to get the file path" -- no, you cannot. A `Uri` is not a file. You can pass the `Uri` to things like `MediaPlayer`, and you can use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to read in the MP3-encoded bytes.

Comment: My motive is same @CommonsWare that we can use this `URI`to get the file

Comment: By the way thanks @CommonsWare I am not so good in English. Now I have updated my answer.